# C++ Data Structures Programming: Passing Values by Reference?

Tags: c++, function, class, pass-by-reference

I've done this C++ data structures program is mostly correct, however I am having trouble with the `RefFunction()` parameters. They are not designed quite properly. They are not supposed to be pass by value, but rather pass by reference and I'm not sure how to do that. It takes a reference to an `int`, and a reference to a `double`. It queries the user to input values to be stored in the variables referenced by its arguments. Then be able to return in the class instance and print the values in `main()`. I greatly appreciate any help as I am very stuck. Thank you very much.

Header file:

```
#ifndef Prog1Class_h
#define Prog1Class_h


//A data structure of type Prog1Struct containing three variables
struct Prog1Struct
{
    int m_iVal;
    double m_dVal;
    char m_sLine[81];
};

// A class, Prog1Class, containing a constructor and destructor
// and function prototypes
class Prog1Class
{
public:
    Prog1Class(); 
    ~Prog1Class(); 

    void PtrFunction(int *, double *);
    void RefFunction(int, double);
    void StructFunction(Prog1Struct *);
};

#endif
```

.CPP file

```
#include "Prog1Class.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Prog1Class::Prog1Class() {}
Prog1Class::~Prog1Class() {}

// PtrFunction shall query the user to input values to be stored in the
// variables referenced by it's pointer arguments
void Prog1Class::PtrFunction(int *a, double *b)
{
    cout << "Input keyboard values of type integer and double"<<endl; 
    cin>>*a >>*b;
}

// RefFunction shall be a C++ Reference function and shall query the user to
// input values to be stored in the variables referenced by it's arguments
void Prog1Class::RefFunction(int a, double b)
{
    cout << "Input keyboard values of type integer and double"<<endl;
    cin >>a >>b;
}

// StructFunction shall query the user to input values to be stored in the
// three fields of the data structure referenced by its argument
void Prog1Class::StructFunction(Prog1Struct* s)
{
    cout << "Input keyboard values of type integer and double"<<endl; 
    cin >>s->m_iVal>>s->m_dVal;
    cout <<"Input a character string";
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    cin.getline(s->m_sLine, 81, '\n'); 
}
```

Comment: Please avoid pointers: In your case it is just void fn(int&, double&).

Comment: Passing by value is not bad, but changes are not passed to the caller: 'void Prog1Class::RefFunction(int a, double b)'

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you don't need to use pointers to pass by reference.

Declare the function like this:

```
void Prog1Class::RefFunction(int& a, double& b)
```

The changes you make to a and b inside `RefFunction` will be reflected in the original variables

Comment: Thank you very much, the program compiles and runs correctly now.

Comment: "In C++, you don't need to use pointers to pass by reference." I would say that you NEVER "use pointers to pass by reference". Using pointers is pass by value.